Mock a repository request
I try to Mock a request to my database following these 2 guides and one SO question:

Mocking dependencies
Testing database
Mock 2 repositories

So I have this code:
   public static function kernelAndService(): array
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel(['environment' => 'test']);
        $mangaService = static::getContainer()->get(MangaService::class);
        $categoryRepository = static::getContainer()->get(CategoryRepository::class);

        return [
            [$kernel, $mangaService, $categoryRepository]
        ];
    }

   /**
     * Test utilisant un mockage de données
     * @dataProvider kernelAndService
     */
    public function testGetBestOfTwoMangasByCategoryMock(
        KernelInterface $kernel,
        MangaService $mangaService,
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ): void
    {
        // Boot du kernel pour accéder au container et déinir nos classes mockées
        $kernel->boot();
        $container = $kernel->getContainer();

        // Mockage de notre classe MangaRepository
        $mangaRepository = $this->createMock(MangaRepository::class);
        $mangaRepository->expects(self::any())->method('getBestOfThreeMangasByCategory')
            ->withAnyParameters()
            ->willReturn([
                new Manga(),
                new Manga(),
            ])
        ;

        // Mockage de l'entity manager pour lui passer notre repository
        $entityManager = $this->createMock(ManagerRegistry::class);
        $entityManager->expects(self::any())->method('getManager')->willReturn($entityManager);
        $entityManager->expects(self::any())->method('getRepository')
            ->withAnyParameters()
            ->willReturn($mangaRepository);

        $container->set(EntityRepository::class, $entityManager);
        $container->set(MangaRepository::class, $mangaRepository);

        $category = $categoryRepository->findOneBy(['name' => 'Ninja']);
        $mangas = $mangaService->getBestOfThreeMangasByCategory($category);

        assertCount(2, $mangas);
    }

Upon the assertion, I have this error message: Failed asserting that actual size 1 matches expected size 2.
In my mock, I created 2 mangas entity while I have one in database and after dumping the $mangas variable, I check that it contains the database result instead of the mocking expected result.
How can I mock my repository correctly ?
Symfony version, is 6.4.

Why should the CategoryRepository access the database, but you mock the MangaRepository?

It is temporary, it will be mocked once I get it working

Can you please remove anything irrelevant to the question. I also don't understand why you are trying to put something in the container.

I was doing accordingly to the Symfony 6.4 guide: https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/testing.html#mocking-dependencies in which they set the repository into the container.

I found the solution by getting my service again after setting the repository in the container. My service was initialized in the dataProvider with the non mocked MangaRepository in the constructor.
// Mocking
$mangaRepository = $this->createMock(MangaRepository::class);
$mangaRepository->expects(self::any())->method('getBestOfThreeMangasByCategory')
        ->withAnyParameters()
        ->willReturn([
            new Manga(),
            new Manga(),
]);

// Add mock repository to container 
$container->set(MangaRepository::class, $mangaRepository);

// Get a new service class initialized with mocked repository
$mangaService = $container->get(MangaService::class);

Then my reqest respond with my mocked result instead of the database result.
